# How to check for an NSNotification in an if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to run the following code, unless a `NSNotification` is sent. I can't figure out how to put the `NSNotification` in the if statement:

```
if (!self.subViewControllerProv) {
    self.subViewControllerProv = [[ProvViewController alloc] init];
}


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"SomeNotification" object:nil];
```

to recap: if the `NSNotification` message is observed then `alloc` and `init` the `ProvViewController` if not then don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well what about doing something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification) name:@"SomeNotification" object:nil];
```

and then

```
-(void) handleNotification {
    //BOOL _hasBeenSent in your interface
    _hasBeenSent = YES;
}
```

And then in your code

```
if(_hasBeenSent) {
    NSLog(@"The notification has been sent!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding an instance variable holding a flag for whether the notification has fired or not, set the flag in -handleNotification:, and then check for if when appropriate.

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    _notificationWasPosted = YES;
}

...

if (!_notificationWasPosted && !self.subViewControllerProv) {
    self.subViewControllerProv = [[ProvViewController alloc] init];
}
```